# Is $F: B(H)\to B(H\otimes K)$, $X\mapsto X\otimes \mathbb{1}_K$ completely contractive?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Take Hilbert spaces $H$ and $K$. Consider a linear map $F: B(H)\to B(H\otimes K)$, $X\mapsto X\otimes \mathbb{1}_K$.

Is it true that $F$ is completely contractive? If it is, I would be very grateful for references.

Comment: It is a complete isometry, with respect to the standard operator space structures on both sides. The particular statement you give is a special case of "injective $*$-homomomorphisms are isometries" applied to each matrix level

Comment: So I am not sure if there is an explicit reference as such; the statement seems to follow from the fact I stated, and the way that the standard matrix norms are defined for Cstar algebras